# Array delete where the pointer to the array is not pointing to the start of the array

Tags: c++, arrays

I came across some code in a very old application I am debugging and I fixed it, but I am not sure what the actual behavior is.

So for instance:

```
char* p = new char[10];
delete[] p;
```

So this works because the runtime keeps track of the head of the array and when you delete[] it knows to delete 10 bytes? At least that's what I understand.

However, if some brainiac does this:

```
char* p = new char[10];
p += 5;
delete[] p;
```

What happens?  It should not work, right?  You are trying to delete an array, but at the current location of p the runtime cannot determine what array you are trying to delete.

Comment: ***What happens?  It should not work, right?*** This is Undefined behavior.

Comment: And this is why you should prefer containers such as `std::vector` and `std::array` (or using smart pointers if you really require pointers) to working with raw pointers and arrays

Comment: @UnholySheep That's a **smart** idea. See what I did there?

Comment: Thanks Baum, I could not find any answers, probably did not have the correct search string.